# Consulta MySql desde una pagina en asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

Estoy intentando implementar este fragmento de codigo

```
public List<int> Temperatura()
        {
            List<int> Datos = null;
            string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=sensores;port=3306;password=123456;";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
                conn.Open();

                string sql = "Select temperatura From datos where fecha  between '" + Label3.Text + "' and '" + Label4.Text + "';";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {

                    Datos.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rdr[0]));
                }
                rdr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            conn.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            return Datos;
```

pero al momento de cargar el list se salta esa parte y no trae todos los datos, no se si es por el getValue o como es que debe adjuntar los datos

Comment: El campo `fecha`en tu base de datos, de que tipo es?

Comment: en la base de datos esta como datetime

Comment: Mira mi respuesta a ver si te sirve.

Comment: Y te toca manejar horas, minutos, etc... también? Que valores esperas en tus labels? y enel campo de tu tabla en la base de datos?

Comment: *al momento de cargar el list se salta esa parte y no trae todos los datos* ¿Qué sería eso? Que consulta pero no trae todo lo que esperás o que no consulta directamente?

Comment: Tu lista debes iniciarla así antes de llenarla: `List<int> Datos=new List<int>();`

Answer (score 1):

Si el campo `fecha` en la base de datos esta como `DateTime`, no tiene sentido que en la consulta le pases la fecha como string. Prueba esto:

```
DateTime fecha1=DateTime.Parse(Label3.Text);
DateTime fecha2=DateTime.Parse(Label4.Text);
string sql = "Select temperatura From datos where fecha between @fecha1 and @fecha2";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha1", fecha1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha2", fecha2);
```

De esta manera, por un lado utilizas una consulta parametrizada que evitará la posibilidad de un sql injection, y por el otro pasas un datetime a la consulta que es lo que realmente se espera.